# AngularFire2 map date to timestamp and vice versa

Tags: typescript, angularfire2

I have an object which contains a date. I want to save my dates as a timestamp. How I map the date to a timestamp when saving and converting it to a date when retrieving?

```
export class MyObject{
    date: Date;
}

let myDate= this.db.list('/my/path');//retrieving
this.db.list('/my/path').push(newItem)//inserting
```

Answer (score 2):

Say you have an interface defined like:

```
export interface Item { ..., updatedAt: any }
```

When writing,

```
newItem.updatedAt = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP; // then push..
```

When reading,

```
{{newItem.updatedAt | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy h.mma'}}
```

[Document is here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue)

**[EDIT]** Now if you have a Date object to map to firebase database, as json doesn't support date, the mapping should be done manually. One option is to save and retrieve as number(epoch time) just like firebase does:

```
export interface Item { ..., updatedAt: any, date: number }
newItem.date = new Date().getTime(); // or pass in any Date to constructor and save
// to retrieve, convert epoch (1494630428022) to Date
console.log(newItem.date, new Date(newItem.date)); // Sat May 13 2017 11:06:57 GMT+1200
```

[Stackblitz demo for rtdb](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bffuxg?file=app%2Fnote.service.ts)

[Stackblitz demo for firestore](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iqq9xo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnote.service.ts)

Comment: Just because i'm have a date,it does't mean I want to save the current timestamp.

Comment: what type is firebase? Is that AngularFireDatabase?

Comment: @user1007522 yap, my answer is about Firebase's realtime database and AngularFireDatabase

Comment: I don't find how to get it done with angularfirestore

Comment: @user1007522 I added a demo link above, have a look at `add()` method.